# I cant use pyaudio (record) when i run ubuntu sudo root

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pyaudio

I wrote a code to detect if the audio is above a certain threshold. I am doing this for a bot and I need to import some data from some files and use the keyboard.is pressed but it is a root library so I tried to run it on the root.

THIS IS THE MAIN SOURCE CODE NOT THE BOT

```py
import pyaudio as pa
import math
import struct

from sqlalchemy import false
Threshold = 10000
CHUNK = 2048
FORMAT = pa.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100 # in Hz
swidth = 2
SHORT_NORMALIZE = (1.0/32768.0)





class Recorder:

    @staticmethod
    def rms(frame):
        count = len(frame) / swidth
        format = "%dh" % (count)
        shorts = struct.unpack(format, frame)

        sum_squares = 0.0
        for sample in shorts:
            n = sample * SHORT_NORMALIZE
            sum_squares += n * n
        rms = math.pow(sum_squares / count, 0.5)

        return rms * 1000

    def __init__(self):
        self.p = pa.PyAudio()
        self.stream =self.p.open(
                        format = FORMAT,
                        channels = CHANNELS,
                        rate = RATE,
                        input=True,
                        output=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
        )

    

    def listen(self):
        print('Listening beginning')
        while True:
            print(self.stream)
            input = self.stream.read(CHUNK,exception_on_overflow=False)
            rms_val = self.rms(input)
            print(rms_val)
            if rms_val > Threshold:
                break

a = Recorder()

a.listen()
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: My guess is when you run `sudo python script.py`, the root user doesn't have the packages installed in whichever system python root is trying to use... you can confirm this by adding a few more details, though.